# How to add role to a user based on DM message in DIscord bot

Tags: discord.js

I want to write a discord bot. This bot assign a role to a user when he DM to the bot. The code looks like below. But message.member is null.

```
bot.on('message', async msg => {
if (msg.channel.type != "dm") {
    return;
}
let message = msg.content;
if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    switch (cmd) {
        case 'role':                          
           const guildMember = message.member; （message.member is null）
           guildMember.addRole('<@&439191493169643521>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you're using the wrong `message`. You declared `message` as a variable to be equaled to `msg.content`, so i believe you mistaken it to be `msg`.

Second, the [addRole](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) method takes in an ID or a snowflake. So you can simply just paste the ID of the role in quotation marks inside the method.

Even if you were to make those changes you would still get an error. Why? Because your bot is reading `DM` channels, not `Guild` channels. So doing something like this would not work.

```js
const guildMember = msg.member;
guildMember.addRole('<@&439191493169643521>');
```

I've made some adjustments to your switch statement to make it work.

```js
switch (cmd) {
    case 'role':
        const guild = client.guilds.get('GUILD_ID');
        // grabs the id of the user who messaged the bot
        var dmUser = msg.author.id;
        // this looks for the users id in the guild
        var isMember = guild.members.get(dmUser)

        // if true
        if (isMember) {
            // then add the role
            isMember.addRole('ROLE_ID');
        } else {
            // if not true. send the user this message
            msg.reply('You are not part of ___ guild')
        }
}
```